# Android studio 3.1.3 проблема с Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

После установки Windows 10 установил Android Studio, установил нужные пакеты, но при создании нового проекта вылетает ошибка:

> Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>
> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom'.

[image: Скрин логов]

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

[image: gradle file]

Comment: Так видно же: не может скачать файл `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom`. Попробуйте переподключиться к интернету, перезагрузить компьютер и перезапустить среду разработки. Кстати, у меня файл скачался.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский я вижу  что не может скачать. что поменять в настройках что бы был доступ к файлу по адрессу https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2 в этом вопрос

Comment: А из браузера у вас файл качается?

Comment: @Bakhuss  да качается

Comment: На просторах говорят, возможно вы под прокси? Может, в a studio настройки прокси.